# How can I set default font features for XeLaTeX without explicitly setting a font?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

I would like double quotes to work the good old LaTeX way with XeLaTeX. Browsing around a bit, this seems achievable using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\begin{document}
``Quotes''
\end{document}
```

However, that does not seem to have any effect until I actually select a font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular}

\begin{document}
``Quotes''
\end{document}
```

Is there some way to achieve this without being specific about the font? I would like this to work without risking that I ask for a font that is missing on other users' systems. That is, can I somehow say `\setmainfont{\WhateverFontYouWouldPickByDefault}` or something equivalent that brings the `Ligatures` feature into effect?

Comment: I get the expected quotes from the first example. What TeX distribution are you running? What version of `fontspec`?

Comment: It should work by default if your system is not too old.

Comment: Using Texlive 2016. I just left the office so I cannot check the fontspec version until tomorrow

Comment: ligatures=tex has been the default for several years (texlive 2014 I think)

Comment: What could be making them not show up on my system, them?

Comment: Could it be that the default font when not using the \setmainfont above cannot show them?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen No. It is using Latin Modern anyway. Also, it works for me with or without loading `fontspec`.

Comment: add `\listfiles` to your first test example (the one that doesn't work) and show the filelist generated at the end of the log.

Comment: And add \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 to your document to see which fonts xetex is using -- your problem to load fonts by filename could be relevant here too.

Comment: At least, it should be using Latin Modern. As a quick check, you can see which fonts are used in your PDF viewer's list of properties for the file.